# CP Session expires after short time

Tags: control-panel, login, session

Our Craft installation is now working on the Production Cloud-Server, except that if I'm logged in the CP, after maybe 30 sec the login-modal pops up and says that the session has expired.
If I just reload the CP, I'm in again without the need to login.

That behaviour didn't show up on the development server.
I didn't make any Configuration Settings like userSessionDuration or something like that, that's all default.

Any idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting "Session Ended" popup in admin](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/getting-session-ended-popup-in-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

99% of the time when you see this behavior, it's because wherever your server is configured to save PHP's session files to either doesn't exist or isn't writable by PHP.

You can check where that path is by going to `yourdomain.com/admin/utils/phpinfo` and searching for `session.save_path`.

If you have the [overridePhpSessionLocation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#overridePhpSessionLocation) config setting set to `true`, then Craft will set that path to `craft/storage/runtime/cache`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by `session.handler = "memcache"`. I changed it to `session.handler = "files"` and made sure that `session.save_path` was writable and the issue was gone. This obviously didn't fix the cause, but was good enough as a solution for me at that time.