# Craft keeps displaying session timeout prompt

Tags: session

For some reason the admin keeps popping up the session timeout box, it seems after about a minute, even thought I can clearly see in my sessions that they have ages until expiry.

See -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/egfg019cruv3uzn/Screenshot%202015-09-11%2009.39.21.png?dl=0

Also strangely when I refresh the page I'm still logged in. What would be causing this. The site is running on nginx if that would make any difference.

Comment: These should get you pointed in the right direction: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/migrated-server-now-getting-logged-out-constantly or https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/952/craft-constantly-logging-out-from-admin-area or https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4653/getting-logged-out-of-admin-area-when-refreshing-site or https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/getting-session-ended-popup-in-admin

Comment: No worries... if one of those solve it, let me know and I'll vote to close this as a duplicate.