# Getting logged out of admin area when refreshing site

Tags: users, admin, session

The problem seem to be that the session file in `/craft/storage/runtime/sessions` is getting removed any time I refresh the actual page, so that I have to do a new login everytime I've changed content, looked at the site, and then want to add more content.

This i running on Apache, PHP 5.3.29, locally through MAMP on Yosemite.

Is there some config setting I'm missing here?

Comment: Ok, don't really think it counts as a solution, more of a workaround, but setting 'userSessionDuration' to false in /craft/config/general.php prevents this from happening.

Comment: There's also a number of good answers at *[Craft constantly logging out from admin area](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/952/craft-constantly-logging-out-from-admin-area)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was actually Chrome using iOS emulation when viewing the site, thus spoofing the UA string into something different than the usual Chrome UA string when logging into the admin area.

Solution (as suggested by @craftcms on Twitter) was to set:

```
'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false
```

In

```
craft/config/general.php
```

For whatever environment you are having the issue.

Answer (score 2):

*As Brad Bell mentioned in [this answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/9629/5437):*

It can be that wherever Apache/PHP is configured to save session files doesn't exist or isn't writable.

If you've got the [`overridePhpSessionLocation`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#overridePhpSessionLocation) config setting set to `true`, then that will be in `craft/storage/runtime/sessions` folder.