# Migrated Server, Now Getting Logged Out Constantly

Tags: admin, migration, login

I just moved my site from one MediaTemple (gs) instance to another. I copied and recreated the database on the new server, moved over all the files, and updated the internal references that pointed to the old site. I even cleared out the 'craft/storage/runtime/' folder.

Whenever I am logged in, I almost instantly get logged out. Typically, this is after 30-60 seconds.

[image]

Whether or not I enter in the correct password, the same message comes back up. However, I can go back to the main admin page, and I'm still logged in.

Any ideas what's going on? It seems to be a caching and session issue of some sort, but there is no caching setup on our server, and I cleared my browser cache completely.

Comment: There's a number of good answers at *[Craft constantly logging out from admin area](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/952/craft-constantly-logging-out-from-admin-area)*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely wherever Apache/PHP is configured to save session files doesn't exist or isn't writable.

If you've got the [overridePhpSessionLocation](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#overridePhpSessionLocation) config setting set to `true`, then that will be in `craft/storage/runtime/sessions` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much. This appears to have solved the issue. I went ahead and added the overridePhpSessionLocation config setting and deleted the whole `craft/storage/runtime/` folder. When I logged in again with a private browsing window, Craft recreated all the necessary runtime cache files, and I'm not getting logged out any longer.