# Migrated site - now dashboard keeps logging out

Tags: admin, login, migration, session, dashboard

I've migrated my client's Craft site to a new host. On the front end the site is fine and working as it should.

The problem is with the Craft admin area. I can login, but once logged I can’t access anything other than the main dashboard screen. Clicking any of the links within the dashboard brings up the login screen.

One thing I did try was to remove the `cpTrigger` I’d set in /craft/config/general.php. For a moment I thought this had worked. I could access other areas of the dashboard, but then the dashboard logged me out after a minute or so.

I’ve seen a few other posters with similar issues and have tried solutions that worked for them…

I’ve delete the contents of `craft/storage/runtime`.

I’ve checked the file permissions of `craft/storage/runtime`. They are currently set to 774.

I’ve tried adding the following to craft/config/general.php:

`'overridePhpSessionLocation' => false`
As described here - [Craft constantly logging out from admin area](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/952/craft-constantly-logging-out-from-admin-area/6876#6876)

and also:

`'overridePhpSessionLocation' => true`

As described here - [Migrated Server, Now Getting Logged Out Constantly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/9628/migrated-server-now-getting-logged-out-constantly)

I’ve tried `'requireMatchingUserAgentForSession' => false` too.

Nothing has worked so far.

Is there anything else I could try?

I understand this is likely to be related to permissions for where session files are stored. Are there any questions I should be asking the the hosting company in relation to this? The site is on a shared hosting account.

Any help or advice with this much appreciated.

*** An update... ***

I looked at `/admin/utils/phpinfo` in the dashboard to check where `session.save_path` is pointing.

By default it's set to `/tmp`.

If I add `'overridePhpSessionLocation' => true` to `craft/config/general.php`, the session location is set to:

```
/var/www/vhtdocs/xxxxxxxx/craft/storage/runtime/sessions/
/tmp
```

That looks a bit odd to me? There are two paths – the craft path and the default session path below it. Is that correct?

Comment: Re: your update, that's normal. The first value is the application's current value (Craft), the 2nd is the default global value.  It's more clear if you call `phpinfo()` from a script directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the hosting company and they managed to fix the issue. They whitelisted the cookie name in their varnish caching system.

Answer (score 1):

Just a question; are you on a Nginx server?
I had a similar issue before with a client site. the Nginx configuration was removing the cookies when it cached the page, which redirected to the login page after logging in.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's an Nginx server or not. I'll contact the hosting company and find out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if 774 would be enough permissions on that folder. If the web server is not running as the account user (via ruid or suexec/suphp), or is not in the same group as the account user then it will not be able to write to it. Just throwing it out there.

Comment: I tried 777 as a test and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like a server config issue. The site worked in one place, you moved it, and now you have this issue.

If it's an Nginx server, this may be helpful: [Nginx-Craft](https://github.com/nystudio107/nginx-craft)

Comment: I'll contact the hosting company to see if they can help with regards to the server config. I'll find out if it's an Nginx server too.